# sprintf() and printf() printing multiple lines in console?

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code:

```
void printStudent(Person per) {
  char string[100];

  char firstName[10];
  strcpy(firstName,per.firstName);
  char familyName[20];
  strcpy(familyName,per.familyName);
  char teleNum[10];
  strcpy(teleNum,per.teleNum);
  int gpa = per.StuEmp.stu.gpa;
  int numCourses = per.StuEmp.stu.numCourses;
  float tuFees = per.StuEmp.stu.tuFees;

  sprintf(string, "\n%s %s Tel: %s, GPA: %d, Courses: %d, Tuition: %.2f\n",firstName,familyName,teleNum,gpa,numCourses,tuFees);

  printf("%s",string);
}
```

I am expecting the string to be printed all on one line in the console however it prints in the following format:

```
Bob
 Joe
 Tel: 123456
, GPA: 8, Courses: 6, Tuition: 12345.89
```

I want it to print like so:

```
Bob Joe                              Tel: 123456, GPA: 8, Courses: 6,Tuition: 12345.89
```

Comment: Chances are your strings have embedded newlines.  You should show how you're getting them, like maybe `fgets` which reads up to and including the newline.

Answer (score 1):

The strings in `per` probably end in `\n`, and so the `\n` characters are being copied. When you go to print out the final string, all of those `\n` characters are being printed.